# Django: How save partial filled form state

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I don't know exactly how to ask this question.

The thing is that I have a main view to create new entries in a model. This model has some 1-many relations, so I added a + button to add new entries of this fields (secondary model) in case they did not exist. When I submit this new data I redirect to the previous page (main view), and if you already filled some fields in the main view, that information is lost.

Can someone suggest me what the best way to deal with this would be? 
Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
'main model view'

```
 class OrganismCreate(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
      """Template: //catalog/templates/catalog/organism_form.html"""
      model = Organism
      fields = '__all__'
```

'main model template' (part)

```
<form action="" method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="panel-group">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Add a new entry: </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
    <hr>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <label for="id_inst_own">Owner:</label>
        {% render_field form.inst_own class="form-control" %}
        <a href="{% url 'catalog:institution_create' %}"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle "></i> Add new  </a>
      </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    ...........................................
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span> submit </button>
  </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Then the related model view:

```
def test_f(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        Form = InstitutionForm()
        render(request, 'catalog/institution_form.html')

    if request.method == "POST":
        Form = InstitutionForm(request.POST)
        if Form.is_valid():
            Form.save()
            next = request.POST.get('next', '/')
            return redirect(next)
    pre=request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    return render(request, 'catalog/institution_form.html',{"form" : Form, "pre": pre})
```

And the related model template

```
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
     {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
   <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ pre }}">
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you post some of the code, your view maybe..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually the main view is just a generic CreateView. I added some code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to solve this problem. Here's some suggestions. Not an exclusive list:

1. Save the incomplete model data in the database as as a 'draft' version of the final data. This could be a totally different model or else using the same model (assuming the related fields are nullable) and giving it a 'draft' flag or similar.
2. Use an inline formset to create the related objects in the same view. Django Extra Views has some useful tools for this (https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views).
3. Using JavaScript, save the unfinished form data to local storage and then recover it when the original form is loaded again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I really appreciate it. About (1 and 3): at what stage could I save the actual state of the fields in the main form? In other words, how to trigger the 'saving' function.? I read about (2), but as I am new to web development I found the doc incomplete... will try to code/test something with it!

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on your code, but here's a possible answer  - for 1, you could post the existing form data to your institution create view, and create the draft model there. Would require a rewrite of that view. For 3, trigger the JS to save to localstorage on click of that `institution_create` link, then redirect manually using JS. I reckon spending the time to understand Django Extra Views is your best bet, it's made for exactly this purpose. The same functionality can be achieved manually though.

Comment: Cool. Thanks! Will give django-extra-views a try!

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a draft system to do this along the lines of 1. in @ChidG's answer.

In models I have something like

```
class AbstractThing(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class CompleteThing(AbstractThing):

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'complete_thing'

class IncompleteThing(AbstractThing):

    fields_to_not_blank = [AbstractThing._meta.get_field(x) for x in []] #if you don't want to change some fields
    for f in AbstractThing._meta.fields:
        if f not in fields_to_not_blank:
            f.blank = True
            f.null = True

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'incomplete_thing'
```

Then you can use model forms and handle the cases in your views.